# Debug SharePoint Apps (Auto-hosted or Provider Hosted)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I can not deploy or debug SharePoint Online Apps (Auto-hosted or Provider Hosted)

I have an Office 365 developer account

My App is Default Asp.net MVC 4 Auto-hosted

When press F5 to Debug the dialog to input my email and password opens and then opens my developer site but doesn't deploy my app

In output window

> Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not
>   specified

Comment: What's in your app? You cannot debug certain things, workflows and event receivers, for example.

Comment: default ASP.NET MVC 4 (Auto-hosted app)

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you are doing, what goes wrong, and what your app does for us to have the slightest chance of helping you

Comment: What happens when you debug?  If it's not getting deployed, check the output in Visual Studio, it should say why it's not getting deployed.